# Lotus Sametime Embedded - Window Format

Tags: lotus-notes, sametime

How to define a chat structure to show the text just below the name (Picture 1) instead of the text next to the name (Picture 2)?

Picture 1
[image: text just below the name].

Picture 2
[image: text next to the name]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is NO setting. These are different versions of the embedded client. They changed it with version 9.0.1 of the embedded client.

**Take care**: Version 9.0.1 of the embedded client did not make it into Notes 9.0.1 until FP9 or FP10, before that it was Sametime 8.5.3 in Notes 9.0.1.

I personally found the "old" way better as well, but there is no setting. If we are lucky this will be fixed in Embedded Client Version 11 as it is an enhancement request posted at [#dominoforever](https://domino.ideas.aha.io/ideas/STC-I-36). Upvote it to enhance the chance of it.